# Open full sized image in another ViewController, that can be Pinched to zoom, like Whatsapp

Tags: swift, image, imageview, scrollview, pinchzoom

guys!
I do an app like messenger, where I can send/receive images. After tapping an image, it should be opened in another controller (FullScreenImageVC). In this controller, this image must have real size, be at the center and can be pinched to zoom. All this  I do programmatically and without any library.

Here is my controller, where I receive an image from previous VC, and where I do all the logic:

```
class FullScreenImageVC: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var startingFrame: CGRect?
var blackBackgroundView: UIView?
var startingImageView: UIImageView?
var imageToSave: UIImage?

var zoomingImageView: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return image
}()

var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scroll = UIScrollView()
    scroll.minimumZoomScale = 1
    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 7
    scroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scroll
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = zoomingImageView.image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.fillSuperView()
    imageView.fillSuperView()

}

static func navigate(_ context: UIViewController, image: UIImageView) {
    let vc = FullScreenImageVC()
    vc.zoomingImageView = image

    vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    context.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.zoomingImageView
}
```

}

Here what I got for now:
[link to GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta1ed.gif)

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/ssowri1/SPPhotoViewer i hope this pod will help

Comment: I only read one view controller in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following To show normal image viewer controller

https://github.com/wxxsw/GSImageViewerController

https://github.com/hyperoslo/Lightbox